# HashMap Keys and Value comparison

Tags: java, dictionary, compare, key-value

I'm comparing HashMap value against the keys and replace if key is larger. The purpose is to update Finger Table of Chord System simulation.

I have HashMap data:

```
Key 0 with Values: [1,2,4,8,16]
Key 3 with Values: [4,5,7,11,19]
Key 7 with Values: [8,9,11,15,23]
```

The desired outcome is such that for each key 0, 3 and 7, its values will be compared with the next key value.

```
Example:
For key 0, compare its values with next key value which is 3.
3 compare with [1,2,4,8,16] and replace 1,2 with 3 because 3 > 1 and 2

For key 3, compare its values with next key value which is 7.
7 compare with [4,5,7,11,19] and replace 4,5 with 7 because 7 > 4 and 5
```

The code written below does the following:

```
For the first set of values [1,2,4,8,16]
1 compare with [0] 
2 compare with [0]
4 compare with [0]
etc.. and it moves on to another set of values

[4,5,7,11, 19]

4 compare with [3]
5 compare with [3]
7 compare with [3]
```

How can I amend the code to achieve the desired outcome mentioned above?

```
public void updateFingerTable() {

        chordSize = chord.initChordSize;

        for (Map.Entry<Integer, node> m : peerList.entrySet()) {

            for (int i=0; i<chordSize; i++) {

                System.out.println("Successor i: " + m.getValue().successor[i]);
                System.out.println ("Key: " + m.getKey());

                if (m.getValue().successor[i] < m.getKey()) {

                    m.getValue().successor[i] = m.getKey();
                    //System.out.println(m.getValue().successor[i]);
                }
            }
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do. Please add more explanation to the example.

Comment: I agree with @amit.  Why are you doing this, and the example is not clear.

Comment: It is still not clear, please add the final output of your query for your provided example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you seem to make the (**wrong!**) assumption that a `HashMap` is *ordered*.

This is not the case!

If you want a map that is ordered by the value of its keys, then you have to use a `TreeMap`. (Alternatively, you could collect all entries from the map, and put them into a list, which you then could sort based on their key).

Apart from that, determining a "next" key in a map is not so simple. (In fact, for a `TreeMap`, you could use the [`higherKey` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#higherKey-K-), but this should not be necessary here).

You can simply walk though the entries, and always refer to the *previous* entry for which you update the list (based on the key of the *current* entry).

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class KeyValueListTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Map<Integer, IntArrayNode> map = new TreeMap<Integer, IntArrayNode>();
        map.put(0, new IntArrayNode(new int[]{1,2,4,8,16}));
        map.put(3, new IntArrayNode(new int[]{4,5,7,11,19}));
        map.put(7, new IntArrayNode(new int[]{8,9,11,15,23}));

        System.out.println("Before update:");
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, IntArrayNode> e : map.entrySet()) 
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        update(map);

        System.out.println("After update:");
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, IntArrayNode> e : map.entrySet()) 
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    private static void update(IntArrayNode node, int minValue)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<node.getNumElements(); i++)
        {
            node.setElement(i, Math.max(minValue, node.getElement(i)));
        }
    }

    public static void update(Map<Integer, IntArrayNode> map) 
    {
        Map.Entry<Integer, IntArrayNode> previous = null;
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, IntArrayNode> e : map.entrySet()) 
        {
            if (previous != null)
            {
                update(previous.getValue(), e.getKey());
            }
            previous = e;
        }
    }
}


class IntArrayNode
{
    private final int elements[];

    IntArrayNode(int elements[])
    {
        this.elements = elements.clone();
    }

    int getNumElements()
    {
        return elements.length;
    }

    int getElement(int index)
    {
        return elements[index];
    }
    void setElement(int index, int value)
    {
        elements[index] = value;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return Arrays.toString(elements);
    }
}
```

For your example input, this will print

```
Before update:
0=[1, 2, 4, 8, 16]
3=[4, 5, 7, 11, 19]
7=[8, 9, 11, 15, 23]

After update:
0=[3, 3, 4, 8, 16]
3=[7, 7, 7, 11, 19]
7=[8, 9, 11, 15, 23]
```

Comment: I have incorporated this to my program and managed to get the intended result. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

you can consider value as dynamic array of Integer that can be implemented using ArrayList and key as Integer.You can code like this for your purpose:

```
List<Integer> value=new ArrayList<>();
       for (Map.Entry pair : map.entrySet()) 
       {

        Integer key=(Integer)pair.getKey();
        for(Integer x:(ArrayList<Integer>)(pair.getValue()))
        {
            if(key>x)
            {
                value.add(key);
            }
            else
            {
                value.add(x);
            }

        }
        map.put(key, (ArrayList<Integer>) value);
        System.out.println(value);
        value=new ArrayList<>();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I see two issues from first glance that seems to violate the logic of your examples.

According to your examples, map values of current element must be compared to map key of **next** element, not **current**.

1. First, line with `for (int i=0; i<chordSize; i++) {`: I was expecting that you would loop over m.getValue().length() so you can iterate values that are associated with `m`, not with `chordSize` which seems to be involved with this Map, though I’m not sure why.
2. Second, line with `if (m.getValue().successor[i] < m.getKey()) {` I think you’ll need to compare `m.getValue().successor[i]` with **next** element’s key, not **current** element’s key.

Having that in mind, you'll need to put all map items into another data structure that provides you with index based access (array seems OK, cause you already know the size of the map) to its components so you'll be able to get next map item while also working with current one. That will make comparing a lot more easy.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, I agree with you on using m.getValue().length() is the proper way to do it. In fact, chordSize is equal to same value. So I use chordSize instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I fear your example is still a bit unclear. Is the following what you want to do:

```
3 keys [0,3,7] 
Three sets of values: [1,2,4,8,16], [4,5,7,11,19], [8,9,11,15,23]

Step 1):

You take the 0 from the keys and compare it with the values: 
0 > 1? No ... 0>16? No.

Step 2): 

Compare the 3 from the keys with the values: 
3>1? Yes -> Replace 1 with 3 ... 3>16? No ... 

Step 3):

Compare the 7 from the keys with the values:
7>1 Yes -> Replace 1 with 7, 7>2? Yes -> Replace...
```

If yes, why bother to compare the smaller keys? The key 7 will "override" all changes that 0 and 3 have done before, so simply find the biggest key and compare it with the values.

```
int keyArray[] = new int[]{0,3,7};

int largest = keyArray[0];

for(int i=1; i< keyArray.length; i++)
{
if(keyArray[i] > largest)
    largest = keyArray[i];                       
}
```

Then you could go over your valuesets and compare them with `largest.equals()` to the HashMap.

Comment: Hi, the reason why I cannot find largest and replace is because for I am trying to simulate chord system where the value lesser than next key is to be replaced with next key.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class Test {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Map<Integer, List<Integer>> hash = new HashMap<Integer,List<Integer>>();
        List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list1.add(1);list1.add(2);list1.add(4);list1.add(8);list1.add(16);
        List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list2.add(4);list2.add(5);list2.add(7);list2.add(11);list2.add(19);
        List<Integer> list3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        list3.add(8);list3.add(9);list3.add(11);list3.add(15);list3.add(23);
        hash.put(0,list1);
        hash.put(3,list2);
        hash.put(7,list3);

        System.out.println("Input:");
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Integer>> m1 : hash.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Successor i: " + m1.getValue());
            System.out.println ("Key: " + m1.getKey());
        } 

        Map<Integer, List<Integer>> out = hash;
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int keyValue = 0;
        int count=0;
        for (Entry<Integer, List<Integer>> m : hash.entrySet()) {

            if(count==0){
                list = m.getValue();
                keyValue = m.getKey();
                count++;
                continue;
            }
            else{

                for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
                    if(m.getKey()>list.get(i)){
                        list.set(i, m.getKey());
                    }
                }
                out.put(keyValue,list);
                list = m.getValue();
                keyValue = m.getKey();
            }


        }

        System.out.println("Output:----------------");
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<Integer>> m1 : out.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Successor i: " + m1.getValue());
            System.out.println ("Key: " + m1.getKey());
        } 

    }

}
```